# How to parse string from the last space in a dynamic string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Say I have a `string`

```
LineOfText = "UserName1 Password1 UserName2 Password2"
```

How would I just grab the last word '`Password2`'

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way would be:

```
Dim lastWord As String = LineOfText.Split(" ").Last
```

Not the most efficient but unless you have a very big string it should be OK.

Comment: @Boo: Wow exact same answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

combine the functionality of substring and lastindexof.

So

```
lineoftext.substring(lineoftext, lastindexof(lineoftext, " "))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim tWord As String = LineOfText.Split(" ").Last
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that is also backwards compatable (pre .Net)...

```
Dim strLastWord As String = Right(LineOfText, Len(LineOfText) - InStrRev(LineOfText, " "))
```